# avoid passing dbsession object to multiple modules

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a project which has a service-oriented architecture. for example, anything relates to `payment` is inside payment module.

```
-dao
-config
-constatnts
-middlewares
-modules
  -payment
  -user
  -bankTransaction
  -...
-routes
```

and expect of mongoose models, all codes are inside the module.
now I want to use mongoDb `session` for running the query in `Transaction` mode. so I want to `bankTransaction` service starts a mongoose `session` and call a `donePayment` method from `payment` modules and should pass `DBsession` to this function. and `donePayment` call `setGoalPayment` of another module and its again should pass `DBsession` object to that.
is there any way to use something like singleton in `java` here?
something that stays upper level of modules and each module could access it.

Comment: Why are you tying the database to your domain model?